# Using PG Backups to import database to app on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I recently learned via this [long discussion](https://github.com/ricardochimal/taps/issues/92) that `heroku db:push` was being depreciated. I attempted to follow the recommended [Heroku's guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export) on importing a database dump to my web app, but am having trouble understanding (and I apologize if the nature of the question is really noob), is what is meant by the line:

```
PGPASSWORD=mypassword pg_dump -Fc --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U myuser mydb > mydb.dump
```

I imagine that this line asks for quite a bit of customization, but as I have little (none) experience dealing with PG, I don't know what (or where along this line) I should be customizing, or whether this would implicate additional steps required of me.

Also, I wanted to ensure that this line:

```
heroku pgbackups:restore DATABASE 'http://f.cl.ly/items/1q2o3t1d3g0F1j2g3z18/mydb.dump'
```

The listed url will need to be customized to that of an url specified by me.

Thanks, for your patience and help!

Answer (score 4):

Breaking down each part of the statement for you:

```
PGPASSWORD=mypassword pg_dump -Fc --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U myuser mydb > mydb.dump
```

mypassword -> input the password for your pg-db dump

-F -> format of the dump

-c -> refers to a custom format

--no-acl -> Prevent dumping of access privileges (grant/revoke commands)

--no-owner -> Do not output commands to set ownership of objects to match the original database

-h -> Specifies the host name of the machine on which the server is running.

localhost -> The name of the host above

-U -> User name to connect as.

myuser -> Your username for above

mydb > mydb.dump ->  dump a database called mydb into a SQL-script file:

In summary, change the "mypassword", "localhost", "myuser", and "mydb" parts to reflect the details of your pg dump, and you're good to go!